# Получить имя файла из Gtk FileChooserButton

Tags: c++, gtk, glade

Собрал интерфейс в Glade и подключил по одному из гайдов на Хабре, а дальше понятия не имею, как мне получить полный путь к файлу, который выбрал пользователь... Вот то, что сейчас у меня в Source.cpp:

```cpp
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

string platform = "unchosen";
bool generatessdts = true;
fs::path dsdtpath = "to be determined";

static GtkWidget* create_window (void) {
GtkWidget *window;
GtkBuilder *builder;
GError* error = NULL;
builder = gtk_builder_new ();
if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "OCConfigGTK.glade", &error)) {
g_critical ("Cannot load file: %s", error->message);
g_error_free (error);
}
else {
gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
if (!window) {
g_critical ("Error occured while accessing widget...");
}
g_object_unref (builder);
return window;
}
return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
GtkWidget *window;
gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
window = create_window();
if (window != NULL) {
gtk_widget_show (window);
gtk_main ();
}
else {
cout « "Failure occurred while trying to create window...\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

А вот содержимое файла OCConfigGTK.glade:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!— Generated with glade 3.22.2 —>
<interface>
<requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
<object class="GtkWindow">
<property name="name">window</property>
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="title" translatable="yes">OpenCore Configurator</property>
<property name="window_position">center</property>
<property name="default_width">300</property>
<property name="default_height">450</property>
<property name="icon">/home/sqd/Downloads/icon.png</property>
<child type="titlebar">
<placeholder/>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkBox">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="margin_left">7</property>
<property name="margin_right">7</property>
<property name="margin_top">7</property>
<property name="margin_bottom">7</property>
<property name="orientation">vertical</property>
<property name="spacing">8</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Welcome, OpenCore Configurator!
by scriptSQD</property>
<property name="justify">center</property>
<attributes>
<attribute name="font-desc" value="Monospace 10"/>
<attribute name="style" value="normal"/>
<attribute name="scale" value="1"/>
</attributes>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="fill">True</property>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkComboBoxText">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="margin_left">30</property>
<property name="margin_right">30</property>
<property name="active">0</property>
<items>
<item id="0" translatable="yes">Select platform:</item>
<item id="1" translatable="yes">Sandy Bridge</item>
<item id="2" translatable="yes">Skylake</item>
<item id="3" translatable="yes">Coffee Lake</item>
</items>
<signal name="changed" handler="setPlatform" swapped="no"/>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="fill">False</property>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkCheckButton">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Include SSDT's</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">False</property>
<property name="halign">center</property>
<property name="valign">center</property>
<property name="active">True</property>
<property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
<signal name="toggled" handler="includeSsdt" swapped="no"/>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="fill">True</property>
<property name="position">2</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkGrid">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="halign">center</property>
<property name="margin_left">10</property>
<property name="margin_right">10</property>
<property name="row_spacing">4</property>
<
 
child>
<object class="GtkFileChooserButton">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">Opens file selection dialog to choose DSDT</property>
<property name="title" translatable="yes">Select DSDT</property>
<property name="width_chars">20</property>
<signal name="file-set" handler="chooseDsdt" swapped="no"/>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="left_attach">0</property>
<property name="top_attach">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Select DSDT:</property>
<property name="justify">center</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="left_attach">0</property>
<property name="top_attach">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="fill">True</property>
<property name="padding">5</property>
<property name="position">3</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<placeholder/>
</child>
</object>
</child>
</object>
</interface>
```

Подскажите, как правильно написать функцию для получения полного пути к выбранному через FileChooserButton файлу?

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался. Не понятна была лишь одна вещь, в Gtk есть метод gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(), в аргументах которого должен быть объект класса FileChooser. Проблема была в том, что я не мог понять, как преобразовать имеющийся FileChooserButton в обычный FileChooser. Итоговая функция выглядит примерно так:

```cpp
void chooseDsdt (GtkFileChooserButton *fileChooser) {
   std::string filepath = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(fileChooser));
}
```